# React Native styling with multi language app using i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next, react-native-stylesheet

My problem is when I create a multi-language app in react native, for example, an app that can be in Arabic and English. when I want to style a component to change the direction when language is switched I always use this type of styling

```
i18n.language == 'ar' ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
```

I tried to use global styling to avoid repeating it in all Views but I can't call i18n outside a component.
any solution to global the style for the languages?

I tried to use global styles but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

you can use I18nManager

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';

if (arabic)
  I18nManager.isRTL = true;
  I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
  I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
else
  ...
```

**check language**

```
if (I18nManager.isRTL) 
 ....
```